# Firefox gets formatted text. IE does not

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, firebug

I've got an anchor element whose text cuts off, and when I click on it, it brings me to a page where the full text is shown in a rich edit text box with new lines and everything.

The problem is when I call the text property of the element in Firefox (firebug) it shows me the full text with editing (new lines and all). However, when I attempt to do the same (or similar) in IE, it does not give me any formatting.

If you need any additional information please let me know, I've been trying this for a little while now.

Here's the title of the anchor: 
15:09 EST New CSR creation via e-mail request Please see attachment for complete details Released to EUS/TMO ------------------------------------

In Firefox

```
window.frames[0].frames[1].document.getElementById('C31_W85_V93_text_table[1].lines').text;
```

Yields:

```
15:09 EST

New CSR creation via e-mail request
Please see attachment for complete details
Released to....
```

There's more but the point is, it's formatted.

In IE

```
window.frames[0].frames[1].document.getElementById('C31_W85_V93_text_table[1].lines').innerText;
```

It just gets everything on one line.

Comment: How about you show the code.

Comment: It works fine for me using the devtools in IE 11. My test case: On https://bugzil.la/911721 I inspected the issue description, then right-clicked the node inside the *DOM Explorer* and chose *Edit As HTML* from the context menu. => The HTML can be edited including the newlines.